# Recursively Merging 2 "Virtual Lists" together into one

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, arraylist, merge

Before you read the problem: No, I'm not trying to get you to write code for me, I just want a few pointers

I have a problem with a MergeSort algorithm I'm writing up. The specifications of the code state that I can only use ONE ArrayList for the act of merging. For example:

With an ArrayList of [5, 1, 3, 9, 2], I would recursively split the list up into

- [5, 1, 3] and [9, 2]
- I would split each of these sub lists AGAIN into:
- [5, 1] and [3] ---------- and [9] and [2];

Now, I would sort the arrayList [5, 1] into [1, 5] and then I would have one whole array containing the numbers:

- [1, 5, 3, 9, 2]

Remember, at this point, I have not created ANY new ArrayLists, I have just sorted within the small sublists that I have. So, going back to recursion, I would then merge the list with [1, 5] with the list [3]. Now, how would I go about doing something like that without having to create a brand new ArrayList to store temporary information?

Anyways, once I have [1, 3, 5, 9, 2], I would then sort out the second sublist, [9, 2], and get [1, 3, 5, 2, 9]. Then I would need to "virtually" merge [1, 3, 5] and [2, 9] to get [1, 2, 3, 5, 9]. How would I go about "virtually" merging these lists (in essence, shifting indices over without having to create a new ArrayList).

This is the code I have so far:

```
    int counterFromStart = first;
    int counterFromMid = mid + 1;

    while (counterFromStart < counterFromMid && (counterFromMid <= last)){
        if (a.get(counterFromStart).compareTo(a.get(counterFromMid)) > 0){
            Comparable temp = a.get(counterFromStart);
            a.set(counterFromStart, a.get(counterFromMid));
            a.set(counterFromMid, temp);
            counterFromMid++;
        }     else {
            counterFromStart++;
        }
    }
```

Also, I have solved this lab in a different way, but not with the method of merging:

With each sublist, I ran through it with insertionSort to sort the two sublists, but again, this is not what "merging" really is: My code, for that method however, is below:

```
    for (int outer = first + 1; outer <= last; outer++){
        int positionInSubList = outer;
        Comparable insertObject = a.get(positionInSubList);

    while (positionInSubList > 0 && a.get(positionInSubList - 1).compareTo(insertObject) > 0){
            a.set(positionInSubList, a.get(positionInSubList - 1));
            positionInSubList--;
        }
        a.set(positionInSubList, insertObject);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727030/mergesort-in-java) will help.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the input! The only problem, however, with that link is that the person created a new array to store information with this line:

int[] a = new int[totElem];

Comment: Sorry, missed out that in your question. Try [this](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/inplacestablesort.html) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm).

Comment: Thanks again for the help! I also found a better link here to anyone for future reference: http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd300/Topic/AdvSorting/MergeSorts/InPlace.html

Kinda sucks that there is no ArrayList alternative for System.arraycopy :(