# Files operations

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a text file with a list of words which I need to sort in alphabetical order using Java. The think is I need to do it without storing in collection or Array in java but you can create temp file.

```
    FileReader r1 = new FileReader("C:/Users/394286/Desktop/file11.txt");
    FileReader r2 = new FileReader("C:/Users/394286/Desktop/file21.txt");
    BufferedReader f1 = new BufferedReader(r1);
    BufferedReader f2 = new BufferedReader(r2);

    String s = null;
    s = f1.readLine();
    String s1 = f2.readLine();

    Set<String> l1 = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> l2 = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> l3 = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> l4 = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> same = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> diff1 = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> diff2 = new TreeSet<String>();

    if (s1 == null && s == null){
        System.out.println("Both the Files are Empty");

    } else if (s1 == null && s != null) {
        System.out.println(" File 2 is Empty");

    } else if (s1 != null && s == null) {
        System.out.println("File 1 is Empty");

    }

    while (s != null){
        l1.add(s);
        s = f1.readLine();
    }

    while (s1 != null){
        l2.add(s1);
        s1 = f2.readLine();
    }
```

this is my try

Comment: Show us what you have attempted, please don't come asking here for us to write your homework.

Comment: Store all the words of the file in TreeSet but it will remove the duplicates word make sure

Comment: I used TreeSet method to do that but I need to do without storing content of file in collections.

Comment: So update the question.You dont specify this

Comment: Then you can store in the array and sort it .

Comment: I don't want to store content of file anywhere but file need to be sorted ,if you you have any solution let me known.@Youngistan

Comment: @user3410052, You can't sort the file content inside the file itself. I guess you should check your problem statement once more

Comment: Then you have to read the file using FileReader and store it in collection.Sort the words using any logic(collection\array) and close it.Then use FileWriter to write the content to that file while iterating from collection.I guess it will help you @user3410052

Comment: welcome dear . so your issue is resolved correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Read words from the file and store in plain array ex. `String[] words`. And now you can sort this array using defined sorting algorithm.(ex. marge sort or selection sort).

[Help in marge sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727030/mergesort-in-java)
[Help in selection sort](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/selection-sort/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] strArr = // get all the Strings from the file and save it in array
Arrays.sort(strArr);// Sorts the Array
```