# How to merge sort? just needed to know where I got Wrong

Tags: java, sorting, merge

I have starting to program in java and trying to learn merge sort. I got the algorithm and was coding with it. I didnt understand what part i got wrong. can someone please help me with this to understand merge sort and debug this code.

```
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     // Merge Sort

    int[] myArray = {2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7};


        mergeSort(myArray);
        System.out.println((Arrays.toString(myArray)));
    }
    public static void mergeSort(int []toSortArray){
       int n= toSortArray.length;
       if (n < 2) {
        return;
       }
    int mid = n/2;
    int [] Left= new int [mid];
    int []Right = new int[n-mid];
    for(int i=0;i<mid-1;i++){
        Left[i]=toSortArray[i];
    }
    for(int i=mid;i<n-1;i++){
        Right[i-mid]=toSortArray[i];
    }
    mergeSort(Left);
    mergeSort(Right);
    merge(Left,Right,toSortArray);

}

public static void merge(int[] Left, int [] Right, int []SortedArray){
    int nL = Left.length;
    int nR= Right.length;

    int i=0;//Index position for left array
    int j=0;// index of position of Right array
    int k=0;// Index position of sorted Array

    while (i<nL && j<nR){
        if (Left[i]<Right[j]) {
            SortedArray[k] = Left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        if (Right[j]<Left[i]){
            SortedArray[k] = Right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    while(i<nL){
        SortedArray[k]=Left[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    } while (j<nR){
        SortedArray[k]= Right[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What output are you getting currently? Are you getting an error, or just an improperly sorted array?

Comment: I think you need to sort in case n==2 before the stop condition.

Comment: I havent got any errors but it doesnt work execute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mergesort in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727030/mergesort-in-java)

Comment: You asked for help debugging. Here is some: fire up your debugger, and place a lot of breakpoints. Check all your state at each point. Find what is not matching your expectations. This will point you to where the bug is. More tips: use a small input, and run the algorithm by hand (on paper) first. Then you'll know what to expect at each breakpoint. Doing this exercise will teach you 100x more than any answer here will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mergeSort(), the two loops to copy data should be to i < mid (not i < mid-1) and i < n (not i < n-1).

In merge(), the first if should be if (Left[i] <= Right[j])  (not just < ). The second if (Right[j] < Left[i]) can be replaced by an else (no need for a second if).

The following code appears to be working:

```
package x;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = {2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7};
    mergeSort(myArray);
    System.out.println((Arrays.toString(myArray)));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int []toSortArray){
        int n= toSortArray.length;
        if (n < 2) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = n/2;
        int []Left = new int [mid];
        int []Right = new int[n-mid];
        for(int i=0;i<mid;i++){
            Left[i]=toSortArray[i];
        }
        for(int i=mid;i<n;i++){
            Right[i-mid]=toSortArray[i];
        }
        mergeSort(Left);
        mergeSort(Right);
        merge(Left,Right,toSortArray);
    }

    public static void merge(int[] Left, int [] Right, int []SortedArray){
        int nL = Left.length;
        int nR= Right.length;

        int i=0;// index position for Left array
        int j=0;// index position for Right array
        int k=0;// index position for Sorted array

        while (i<nL && j<nR){
            if (Left[i]<=Right[j]) {
                SortedArray[k] = Left[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            } else {
                SortedArray[k] = Right[j];
                j++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        while(i<nL){
            SortedArray[k]=Left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } while (j<nR){
            SortedArray[k]= Right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i changed it as you assumed. the code still doesnt work properly.

Comment: @sanjay - I updated my answer, the first if in merge() needs to be <= (not just <). The second if can be replaced with an else.

Comment: i tred as you said. The program executes but the output is not sorted.

Comment: @sanjay - I added what appears to be working source code to my answer.