# How to print steps when sorting in Java?

Tags: java, sorting

I have one problem. I need to print time and steps of sorting. I did time but I do not how to print steps.

```
class BubbleSort {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 int[] randomNums = new int[20];

for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) {
    randomNums[i] = (int) (100 * Math.random());
}
System.out.println("Numbers before sorting: ");

for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) {

    System.out.print(randomNums[i]+" " );

}
System.out.println();


long time = System.nanoTime();
bubbleSort(randomNums);
long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - time;
System.out.println("\nBubble sort time is " + elapsed + " nanoseconds passed, " + elapsed / 1000000000 + " seconds passed");
}

static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
int numbers = arr.length;
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < (numbers - i); j++) {
        if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
            //swap elements
            temp = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }

    }
}

  }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mergesort in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727030/mergesort-in-java)

Comment: This is not a homework site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For listing down steps we can simply use a sysout to do the thing. The crux here is to know how this sorting algo is actually doing the sorting part. 
 The swapping part is the actual sort code.

```
int step = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < (numbers - i); j++) {
          if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
              //swap elements
              System.out.println("step #" + step + ". swapping " + arr[j - 1] + " and " + arr[j])
              temp = arr[j - 1];
              arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
              arr[j] = temp;
              step++;
          }

      }
}
```